# How would I eliminate parameter to find the Cartesian Equation?

Tags: calculus

$x= -3\cos(t)$
$y= 3\sin(t)$

I know that $x= r\cos(t)$ and $y= r\sin(t)$ but I can't figure out how to separate $x=-3\cos(t)$ so that I can plug it into $y=3\sin(t)$

Comment: You know it is a circle, right?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $x^2 = 9 \cos^2(t)$ and $y^2=9 \sin^2(t)$.

Add them together, $x^2 + y^2 = 9 \cos^2(t)+9 \sin^2(t)=9(\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t))=9$, since $\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)=1$.

So $x^2 + y^2 = 9$.

Answer (score 2):

Examine the expression $x^2 + y^2$.  That will give you an equation to solve for y in terms of x.

Comment: We lose some information when passing to $x^2 + y^2 = 9$, with the consequence that solving "for $y$ in terms of $x$" gives two branches of functional dependence whose phase (angular discplacment around circle) is not the same as for the parameterized trajectory.  That said, the Question only asks us to "eliminate the parameter", so you've achieved that much.

Comment: Right, and we have to deal with branches anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This approach lacks subtlety, and I don't really recommend it in this case.  But, you should be aware of it.

$y = 3 \sin t\\
t = \sin^{-1}\frac y3\\
x = -3 \cos (\sin^{-1}\frac y3)\\
x = -3 \sqrt {1 - \frac {y^2}9}\\
x^2 = 9 - y^2\\
x^2 + y^2 = 9$